# Update Existing Table Based on Value from Another

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I Have Below Two Tables

```
Book Table 
+--------+------+------+--------+
| EmpID  |BookID| Type | Color  |
+--------+------+------+--------+
|      1 |    A |    0 |Blue    |
|      2 |    B |    0 |Black   |
|      3 |    C |    0 |White   |
|      4 |    D |    0 |Blue    |
+--------+------+------+--------+
     ->Color  Can Be only 'Blue' or 'Black' or 'White'
     ->EmpID and BookId are Unique

Settings Table
+--------+------------+--------------+
| EmpID  | Blue       |  Black/White |
+--------+------------+--------------+
|      1 | 0          |      0       |
|      2 | 0          |      1       |
|      3 | 1          |      0       |
|      4 | 1          |      1       |
+--------+------------+--------------+
    ->For Emp1 Blue and Black are Not Allowed
    ->For Emp2 Only Black/White are Allowed
```

I added a New Column Called TYPE on the Book Table and Defaulted it to '0'. Now I need to Update the Value of Type Based on the Logic from Settings Table & Color Column Value.

```
  LOGIC For Updating
 +--------+------------+------------+-------+
| Color  | Blue       | Black/White| TYPE   |
+--------+------------+---------------------+
|  blue  | 0          |      0     |   0    |
|  white | 0          |      1     |   1    |
|  black | 1          |      0     |   0    |
|  blue  | 1          |      1     |   1    |
+--------+------------+------------+--------+
   -> If Color is BLUE and BLUE_SETTING is 1 then TYPE is 1 else 0
   -> If Color is BLACK OR WHITE and BLACK/WHITE Setting is 1 then TYPE is 1 else 0
```

Comment: What does 'Author can only be' mean? There's no `Author` column, it's called `Color`.

Comment: What problem are you having? This sounds like a simple `UPDATE + JOIN`  with `CASE` in the `SET` clause.

Comment: Sorry I meant Color not Author

Comment: My head hurts. :-(